# Wamp orange icon Error

Tags: localhost, wamp, wampserver

How to fix this error when I go to `wamp > apache > services > test port 80`
it says

> port 80 used by Apache/2.4.9  PHP/5.5.12

I tried researching on YouTube but none of them worked because most of their error is their port 80 is used by Microsoft IIS etc whereas mine is different.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your question clearly.

Comment: **That is not an error** That means the Apache is running correctly. What makes you think this is an error!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest if the icon is orange but you get

> port 80 used by Apache/2.4.9 PHP/5.5.12

then Apache is running, but MYSQL is not.

Read the mysql error log

```
wampmanager -> MySQL -> error log
```

If that is empty look at the Windows Event Viewer for message from MYSQL

The most likely problems are

- You are running another MYSQL Server
- You have rouge `my.ini` file somewhere in the C:\windows folder structure
- You have a corrupted database and MySQL cannot recover itself